Import python package from zip
In medium.com article there is a section about accessing the packages stored in the ZIP file using code:
import sys
sys.path.append("my_package.zip")
from my_package import my_code

To test this, I downloaded optbinning 0.19.0 package from PyPi, extracted all files, then zipped the folder with __init__.py file inside and named my file as optbinning_dwnl.zip.
Now, if I try to load package as in the article using code
import sys
import os 

os.chdir("C:\\my_path")
sys.path.append('optbinning_dwnl.zip')
from optbinning_dwnl import OptimalBinning

I receive an error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'optbinning_dwnl". However, If I try to load package from unzipped folder, everything works fine:
import sys
import os 

os.chdir("C:\\my_path")
sys.path.append('optbinning_dwnl')
from optbinning_dwnl import OptimalBinning

So, is it possible to load packages from zip files or not? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

ZIP file act just an entry in sys.path where packages are looked for. If the zip is correctly added to your sys.path, you can just do import optbinning; given that directory structure in the zip is is also correct.

Worth mentioning also is that optbinning has dependencies so importing will fail  if you havent preinstalled those..

Thank you! My .zip structure was indeed incorrect.

To import package from zip file, you need to replicate the full package structure within it. Compressed package with structure like that
optbinning_dwnl.zip
|
| -- __init__.py
| -- code.py

should be changed to
optbinning_dwnl.zip
|
| -- optbinning <dir>
     | -- __init__.py
     | -- code.py

To import package use:
sys.path.append('optbinning_dwnla.zip')
from optbinning import OptimalBinning #name of folder in .zip, not a .zip itself

